# How do I access and know the privileges that I enjoy

Tags: discussion

Recently I got the privilege to *'access review queues'*, but I don't know how to access the queues'. Also, where can I see the privileges I "enjoy" and how to exploit them. I went to [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review), but I didn't find anything **'accessible'** there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't know how to access the queues

At the top-right hand corner:

[image: Review queues]

> where can I see the privileges I "enjoy" and how to exploit them

I wouldn't use the word "exploit", but... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges Again this is accessible from the top right-hand corner:

[image: Privileges]

> I went to Stack overflow, but I didn't find anything 'accessible' there

Privileges only apply on Stack Exchange sites where you have already earned them. If you have earned a privilege on [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com), it doesn't necessarily mean you will have it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: How can I update my *'about me'* section?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC5Yc.png